# PictureThumbnailURL managed property returns pixelated roll up image and published image

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I have a search function that uses the managed property "PictureThumbnailURL" to return a rollup image and published image. However, these images are very pixelated and low quality. Is there any way to solve this and get the original picture/bigger resolution? I use SharePoint Online.

Comment: Where do you use the managed property "PictureThumbnailURL"?

Could you please offer a screenshot?